# Implementation of Composition Instead of Inheritance in Controllers Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, best-practice

I am trying to implement Magento 2 Coding Standard so I found an Article Here -> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Decomposition-of-Magento-Controllers/ba-p/430883

I have changed my frontend And backend Controllers in the same way

Here is an Example

**Frontend Controller:**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;

class HomeRedirect implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    private RedirectFactory $redirectFactory;

    /**
     * @param RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
    ) {
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Check is Allowed
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $this->redirectFactory->create()->setPath('dashboard');
    }
}
```

**, in the same way, I am have implemented an admin controller**

```
use Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory;

class NewAction implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    private ForwardFactory $forwardFactory;

    /**
     * @param ForwardFactory $forwardFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ForwardFactory $forwardFactory
    ) {
        $this->forwardFactory = $forwardFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return Forward
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->forwardFactory->create()->forward('edit');
    }
}
```

Is this right way to do so?

Anyone, please suggest to me any Module in which the composition is implemented on controllers properly

Comment: I think, for now, composition principle is more about writing your custom code. But you are thinking right. it's a bit more complicated, read some blogs about composition, like: https://www.yireo.com/blog/2019-05-18-extending-magento2-classes-by-composition. Magento core cannot rewrite all code from inheritance to composition, it's too massive and complicated.

p.s.
For custom controllers, from latest magento versions, you should only implement interfaces: HttpGetActionInterface, HttpPostActionInterface or just ActionInterface

Comment: we had a discussion on github about this you can check it https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34748